iterating through text boxes in each slide of a powerpoint slide deck misses most text boxes
Edit. Solution below from ChatGPT-3.5-Turbo.
I need to loop through each slide in a slide deck (seems to work) and get the text from every textbox in each slide. The problem is the code I wrote and the code I found on stackoverflow both seem to miss most of the text boxes.

It doesn't see every text box on a page, even though I created them through copy-pastes of the first one created on each page.
It doesn't see the top text box that contains the slide title.

I'm starting with the code at
Powerpoint VBA: Loop to make textboxes visible gets issues when adding bring to front
I modified part of it to read:
    For x = 1 To UBound(aShapeArray)
        Set oShp = aShapeArray(x)
          If oShp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            Debug.Print oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
'            oShp.Visible = True
'            oShp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
          End If
    Next

(I have tried writing code myself from scratch, but I get the same results.)
I have a made up a sample slide deck with just a few slide and text boxes.
it doesn't read any of the title text boxes and it misses a bunch of the other text boxes.
What might I be missing?
I'm not sure the proper way to do this, but I was able to coax chatgpt to give me a solution:
Sub PrintTextInSlide()
    Dim pptSlide As slide
    Dim pptShape As shape
    Dim text As String
    
    ' Loop through each slide in the presentation
    For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Debug.Print "Slide " & pptSlide.SlideIndex & ":"
        
        ' Loop through each shape on the slide
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
            If pptShape.HasTextFrame Then
                If pptShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    text = pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.text
                    Debug.Print "    Shape: " & pptShape.Name & " - " & text
                End If
            End If
        Next pptShape
        
        ' Print slide title separately
        If pptSlide.Shapes.Title.HasTextFrame Then
            text = pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.text
            Debug.Print "    Slide Title: " & text
        End If
        
    Next pptSlide

End Sub

The specific question I asked was, "write vba code to loop through every slide in a powerpoint slide deck, and for each slide loop through every textbox or other container with text in it, including the slide title, and then print the text inside each of these containers to the immediate window"

So you don't have a problem?  It's not clear what the exact question is here?

ChatGPT did a good job here.

Unless you have shapes that have been grouped together, which will be missed

I’m voting to close this question because it's really just a post of some ChatGPT-generated code.

This will also miss text in tables, charts, SmartArt, and probably three other things I haven't thought of.
